# Extract attributes and values from XML file in perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, stanford-nlp

This is part of the output XML file I get as output from Stanford CoreNLP:

```
<collapsed-ccprocessed-dependencies>  
      <dep type="nn">
        <governor idx="25">Mullen</governor>
        <dependent idx="24">Ms.</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="26">said</governor>
        <dependent idx="25">Mullen</dependent>
      </dep>
    </collapsed-ccprocessed-dependencies>
  </sentence>
</sentences>
<coreference>
  <coreference>
    <mention representative="true">
      <sentence>1</sentence>
      <start>1</start>
      <end>2</end>
      <head>1</head>
    </mention>
    <mention>
      <sentence>1</sentence>
      <start>33</start>
      <end>34</end>
      <head>33</head>
    </mention>
  </coreference>
 </coreference>
<mention representative="true">
      <sentence>1</sentence>
      <start>6</start>
      <end>9</end>
      <head>8</head>
    </mention>
    <mention>
      <sentence>1</sentence>
      <start>10</start>
      <end>11</end>
      <head>10</head>
    </mention>
  </coreference>
  <coreference>
```

How do I parse it using Perl so that I get something like this:

```
1. sentence 1, head 1
   sentence 1, head 33
2. sentence 1, head 8
   sentence 1, head 10
```

I have tried with XML::Simple but the output is not easily understandable. Here is what I did: 
    use XML::Simple;
    use Data::Dumper;

```
$outfile = $filename.".xml";
$xml = new XML::Simple;

$data = $xml -> XMLin($outfile);
print Dumper($data);
```

Comment: You're going to have to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably, `XML::Simple` was first to stake its claim for the `Simple` namespace. It is perhaps simple in implementation but not so simple in use except in the most trivial of cases. If you want something similar, then [`XML::Smart`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSmart) offers a nested data-structure API but does it a lot better.

Thankfully there is a lot of choice for excellent Perl XML modules. [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) is one of these, and it allows you to specify callback subroutines that will be executed when specific elements within the XML data are encountered during parsing.

This program uses `XML::Twig`, and sets a callback on `coreference[mention]`, i.e. `coreference` elements that have at least one `mention` child.

The code in the handler subroutine makes no checks and assumes that there will always be at least two `mention` child elements, each with a `sentence` and a `header` element. The text values of these nodes are output in the format you have described.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {
  'coreference[mention]' => \&handle_coreference
});
$twig->parsefile('myxml.xml');

my $n;
sub handle_coreference {

  my ($twig, $elt) = @_;

  my @mentions = $elt->children('mention');

  for my $i (0 .. $#mentions) {
    printf "%s sentence %d, head %d\n",
      $i == 0 ? sprintf '%3d.', ++$n : '    ',
      map $mentions[$i]->first_child_trimmed_text($_), qw/ sentence head /;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
  1. sentence 1, head 1
     sentence 1, head 33
  2. sentence 1, head 8
     sentence 1, head 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I was stuck with this problem for so many days. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I doubt there's always going to be exactly two mentions.

Comment: @ikegami: Unfortunately we know nothing at all about this data. Nevertheless I have generalised the solution as it is also neater that way.

Answer (score 4):

XML::Simple has the hardest interface to use. You could use something like

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);

my $coref_count;
for my $coref_node ($doc->findnodes('//coreference/coreference')) {
   ++$coref_count;

   my $mention_count;
   for my $mention_node ($coref_node->findnodes('mention')) {
      ++$mention_count;

      my $sentence = $mention_node->findvalue('sentence/text()');
      my $head     = $mention_node->findvalue('head/text()');

      my $prefix = "$coref_count.";
      $prefix = ' ' x length($prefix) if $mention_count == 1;

      print "$prefix sentence $sentence, head $head\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting a syntax error saying that the '<' tag is missing. So, I guess I am making a mistake in providing the input. I provided the filename as input. Could you guide me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: You can use `->parse_file($qfn)` if you have a file

Comment: oh, I was using it as -> parsefile probably didn't work because of that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Rules;

my $mention_cnt;
my $ref_cnt = 1;
my @rules = (
  coreference => sub {
    $ref_cnt++ if $mention_cnt;
    $mention_cnt = 0;
  },
  mention => sub {
    my $d = $_[1];
    my $str = $mention_cnt++ ? " " x 6 : sprintf("%-6s", "$ref_cnt.");
    print "$str sentence: $d->{sentence} head: $d->{head}\n";
  },
  'sentence,head' => 'content',
);

my $xr = XML::Rules->new(
  rules => \@rules,
);
$xr->parse($xml);
```

Comment: Note the desired output now that proper formatting has been applied.

Comment: @ikegami - Oh, well, he did say 'something like...' :-) Maybe I'll update, maybe I won't...or anyone w/editing powers can update this answer...

Comment: I am new to perl and still trying to understand the steps involved in parsing a file in addition to a lot of other things. Would really appreciate if you would update it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One quick question, where is the input provided? Is it the $xml variable? I keep getting a syntax error on that line.

Comment: Yes, assuming $xml is a string of XML, as the XML can't just spontaneously create itself. Or it could come from a filehandle, or using parse_file() instead, from a file.